# time and date calculation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a calculated column (Adjusted Date) that will add one day to [Date Received] if a sample is received on/after 12:00PM and on a Monday thru Thursday. add three days to [Date Received] if a sample is received on/after 12:00PM and on a Friday.  Is the formula below close? Thank you.

```
=IF(AND([Time Received]>=12:00PM,[Day Received]<4),[Date Received] +1), =IF(AND([Time Received]>=12:00PM,[Day Received]=5),[Date Received] +3)
```

Comment: Do you have custom fields for [Day Received] and [Time Received]? [Date Received] is also custom field or is mapped to [Created] field (filled in when new item (a sample in your case) is added to list) ?

Comment: [Day Received] is a text field, [Time Received] is also text, Both custom calculated fields. The ideal would be if the conditions above are not met, then Date Received is unchanged, but if the conditions above are met, then [Date Received] is changed accordingly.  There would be no new field needed as the [Date Received] would be controlled by the formula.  Thanks.